# No data returned when i query feedsubscriptionsforentity

Tags: apex

Is there a reason why my soql doesnt return any value when i query this object Entitysubscription in a nested query.It returns value when i run as system admin,but not other users

(query is dynamic as well)
as below

```
selectQuery = 'select name,Total_Number_of_Members__c,lastmodifieddate,( Select SubscriberId ,parentid From feedsubscriptionsforentity  where parentid in :ids limit 1000) from test__C where id in :ids';
```

Any fix for this?

On debugging as non-sys admin user,i can see no data is fetched

I am trying to find total number of followers for this record,and whether running user follows this record.if there is a way to achieve this other than this?

Answer (score 1):

Based on information you provided I can only assume:
There is empty Set, or user don’t have access to those objects, there is wrong relation name etc.

additional:
Why you need these ‘WHERE’ in nested query?
Why you need to use dynamic query? 
Because as I can see there is no point for that